# How to configure chainsaw bundle to view log4j log file?

Tags: log4j

I want to view my log4j log file in chainsaw bundle. My log file pattern is

LOG:%x : %d{ISO8601} : %-5p %c{1} - %m%n

The corresponding pattern to view in chainsaw bundle is needed. I have tried many things, i couldn't represent the 'Log' ':' in chainsaw bundle pattern.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest developer snapshot here instead:
http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

I was able to process these log messages:

- LOG:{blah1=blah2} : 1/1/2011 : DEBUG LOGGER1 - MESSAGE1
- LOG:{blah1=blah2} : 1/1/2011 : DEBUG LOGGER2 - MESSAGE2
- LOG:{blah1=blah2} : 1/1/2011 : DEBUG LOGGER3 - MESSAGE3

Using this logformat and a timestampformat of M/d/yyyy

LOG:PROP(BLAH1) : TIMESTAMP : LEVEL LOGGER - MESSAGE